# Brokers for Celery Executor in Airflow

Tags: celery, airflow, broker

Is it possible to use the following brokers instead of Redis or RabbitMQ:

1. Zookeeper
2. IBM MQ
3. Kafka
4. Megacache

If so, how would I be able to use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per [*Celery*](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) documentation in a part of transport [brokers](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html#broker-overview) support, [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [Redis](https://redis.io/) are fully featured and qualified as a stable solutions.

According to the list you've provided for any alternatives around, [Zookeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) might be also adopted as an Celery executor in Airflow but only as an experimental option with some functional limitations.

Installation details for Zookeper broker implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/210ad35e8c8a0ed26abbec45126700eebec1d0ef/docs/includes/installation.txt).

Using Python package:

```
 $ pip install "celery[zookeeper]"
```

You can check out all the available extensions in the source `setup.py` [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/6b49b0ac9e57cdf9fb6b470c8e343a400713428c/setup.py#L54).

Referencing Airflow documentation:

> **CeleryExecutor** is one of the ways you can scale out the number of workers. For this to work, you need to setup a Celery backend
>   *(RabbitMQ, Redis, …)* and change your `airflow.cfg` to point the executor parameter to `CeleryExecutor` and provide the related Celery
>   settings.

After particular Celery backend being prepared, adjust appropriate settings in `airflow.cfg` file, for any incoming doubts refer to this [example](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/config/airflow.cfg).